# Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop, even though I pass a key={}

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I'm currently working on a ReactJS project and i'm getting this console log

```
index.js:1 Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.
```

main.js

```
function Main() {
    const [cars,setCars] = useState([]);


    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get('/cars')
            .then((res) => {
                setCars(res.data.map((car) => (cars.push(car))));
                console.log(cars);
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err);
            });
    }, [])

    return (
        <div className="main">
                <Navbar/>

                <div className="main__container">
                    {cars.map((car) => (
                        <p key={car.carId}>{car.numberPlate}</p>
                    ))}
                </div>
        </div>
    )
```

}

I console logged the cars array and everything is fine , all the data gets stored correctly into the array but i still get this annoying log and I don't know why.
Initially, I made a react component for each car (where i passed things such as: key (which is the carId), numberPlate and so on from the firebase).
Having that warning then is switched to the current form, where i just want to print out the list of the cars (i don't care about the style atm).

Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `setCars` method is broken:

```
setCars(res.data.map((car) => (cars.push(car))));
```

First, you're mutating the existing state, which you should never do in React. Secondly, `.push` returns the new length of the array.

Set the state to the *returned array itself* - no need to iterate over it and `push`, just pass the array to `setCars`:

```
setCars(res.data);
```

```js
function Main() {
    const [cars,setCars] = React.useState([]);


    React.useEffect(() => {
        Promise.resolve({ data: [{ carId: 1, numberPlate: 'aa' }]})
            .then((res) => {
                setCars(res.data);
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err);
            });
    }, [])

    return (
        <div className="main">
                navbar goes here

                <div className="main__container">
                    {cars.map((car) => (
                        <p key={car.carId}>{car.numberPlate}</p>
                    ))}
                </div>
        </div>
    )
}
ReactDOM.render(<Main />, document.querySelector('.react'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div class='react'></div>
```

Comment: thank you ! Now it's printing out all the data that i wanted !

Answer (score 0):

You could solve the problem by using these two tips.

**Avoid index as element key**

When a list item was added or removed, and the key kept the same, the React assumed that the DOM element had not changed, and the app could not render.

An alternative to cases that the list doesn't have a unique ID is to generate one using [shortID](https://www.npmjs.com/package/shortid).

**Avoid Immutable Data Structures**

Immutable data allow direct use of memory reference and require less process.

We have a common problem using immutable data, trying to compare changes in variables that don't have the same reference.

If some change was made directly in the props, we can't compare like this:

```
React.memo(SomeComp, (props, nextProps) => {
 if (props.prop1 === nextProps.prop1) {
   return true;
 }
});
```

Example:

```
let neymar = { "name": "Neymar", "score": 1 }
neymar.score = 2
console.log(neymar)
 
 
const mbappe = { "name": "mbappe", "score": 0 }
const updateMbappe = {...mbappe, score: 4};
 
console.log(updateMbappe)
```